How to refer to a component as something else
I have to type transform.position.x a lot and I'm pretty sure there's a way to shorten it, but I don't remember how.
There's a way to refer to something else that I think is like this transform.position.x > x to make it so when you type x you're referring to transform.position.x. I know you can just make a variable that updates every frame, but I don't want to do that.

I think what you want is a property:
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    float x => transform.position.x;
}

Now you can use x within the class Foo. Each time you use it, it gets the current value of transform.position.x.
You can also implement it for setting the value of transform.position.x:
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    float x {
        get => transform.position.x;
        set {
            var position = transform.position;
            position.x = value;
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }
}


As you can see such a property is a bad idea since it hides the fact that if you happen to access/wrote this multiple times within a method / frame you will have to read transform.position multiple times which is expensive and should rather be cached where possible
